# From Date to Varchar in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to select data from SQL tables using Spark SQL and tranfer it to Pandas. Doing that:

```
dataset_date=sqlContext.sql('''
Select a.ID, a.STAT, a.Date
from TABLE a''' 
) 
df_date=dataset_date.toPandas()
df_date.head()
```

The column a.Date has Date format and I'd like to switch it to Varchar instead. What function should I use in SparkSQL to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.date_format`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df.withColumn("date", date_format("date", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```